# Progress Dialog in OnCompletion method

Tags: android

I have following code in which Progress Dialog do not shows.

```
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    TrackAnalysis a = null;

    File file = new File(songs.get(index).path);
     final Track track;
    try {
        track = echoNest.uploadTrack(file, true);
        final ProgressDialog dialog2 = ProgressDialog.show(MainGameActivity.this, "Analyzing...", "Please wait...",
                true);
        dialog2.setCancelable(true);
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(3000);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dialog2.dismiss();
                }
            }).start();

        track.waitForAnalysis(30000);
        a = track.getAnalysis();
        Log.i("TUTAJ", a.getTempo().toString() + track.getArtistName() + track.getTitle());
    } catch (EchoNestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

OnCompletion method is  from overloaded MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.

My question is why progress bar do not shows?  When I placed ProgressBar code to onClicked method, then it works fine.

Comment: Have you debugged to make sure you're even getting to onCompletion?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are calling start on media player before you set onCompletionlistener.
on clicked method does not require media player to start before its set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the UI related code on main thread. You could either use [`runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or make use of [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). There are many examples available in the API Guides section of Android Developers site. Please take a look at [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for a start.